# Permissions denied on sql query

Tags: sql, permissions, asp-classic, permission-denied

I'm trying to execute the following query through classic asp recordset -

```
SQL = "Select P_Name as P_Name, P_Description as P_Description 
       from L_PagePermission 
       inner join A_Permission on p_permissionID = pp_PermissionID 
       inner join A_Page on P_PageID = PP_PageID 
       where P_PageID = 85 
       order by p_Name"
```

Although I've ran into a problem with permissions. So the error that i am receiving is -

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC
>   Drivers error '80040e09'
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]SELECT permission
>   denied on object 'A_Permission',
>   database 'HRWB_3_0', schema 'dbo'.

How would I go about executing this query without changing permission settings. How can I do this with a stored procedure? (Can someone provide an example too)

I can't change the database settings I have to deal with what I got. I've looked through a lot of the websites files and it seems to be mostly dependent on stored procedures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not going to be able to get around that permissions error unless you grant select access on the `L_PagePermission` and `A_Permission` tables to the login that you are using to connect to the database, or unless you use a different login that already has select access to those tables.

Another approach would be to write a new stored procedure and grant EXECUTE access to that stored procedure.  The SQL to grant permissions in either case is simple:

To grant SELECT access to a table:
`GRANT SELECT ON [TableName] TO [loginName]`

To grant EXECUTE access to a stored procedure:
`GRANT EXECUTE ON [procedureName] TO [loginName]`

One more approach that could work but has obvious security implications is to add the login you are using to the db_owner role for that database. That should work, but is NOT recommended unless you are comfortable with the security risks that presents.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have permission to select from the table, there won't be any way to work around the absence of permission other than connecting to the DBMS as a user who has permission to select from the table.  That's the point of the permissions system - to prevent the unauthorized from doing what they are not allowed to do.