# uninitialized constant error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Iam working in ruby on rails for fetching the existing db tables from remote server mechine(SQL SERVER) .Actually i don't know how to do this.Am following this way.please rectify me

My problem is while tying to run `uninitialized constant TrDeviceDetailsController::TRDeviceDetail` is getting.

I set the following in `database.yml` file.

```
development:
   adapter: sqlserver
   mode: odbc
   database: BObd
   dsn: newdb_64
   username: ush
   password: Ushu
   host: ws1a20\SQLEXPRESS
```

The table exist in the db `BOdb` is  `TRDeviceDetails`.I created models and controller using the command

```
    rails generate model `TRDeviceDetail`
rails generate controller `TRDeviceDetails`
```

And in controller i put the following

```
class TrDeviceDetailsController < ApplicationController
  def show
        @devices = TRDeviceDetail.find(:all)
  end
end
```

model file

```
    class TrDeviceDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
      # attr_accessible :title, :body
        attr_accessible :UniqueDeviceID
    end
```

where `UniqueDeviceID` is the existing column in table `TrDeviceDetails`
and created a show.html.erb file for displaying the  UniqueDeviceID

```
<h1>TrDeviceDetails#show</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/tr_device_details/show.html.erb</p>
<%@device.inspect%>
```

what i need is,get existing tables from remote machine.How it is possible and why this error is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use

```
@devices = TrDeviceDetail.find(:all) # small 'r'
```

as the generated class is

```
class TrDeviceDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
```

UPDATE:

If the table name is not something that follows convention, you should set the table_name explicitly

```
class TrDeviceDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'TRDeviceDetails'
end
```

Comment: while trying getting this error................ODBC::Error: S0002 (208) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'tr_device_details'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [tr_device_details].* FROM [tr_device_details]'

Comment: you have an unusual model name so there may be issues with connecting to the database. can you check the name of the table in the db for this model?

Comment: TRDeviceDetails is the existing table in the remover sql server

Comment: use better @devices = TrDeviceDetail.all

Comment: ODBC::Error: 42000 (229) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'TRDeviceDetails', database 'BObd', schema 'dbo'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [TRDeviceDetails].* FROM [TRDeviceDetails]'

Comment: that error means that you don't have permission on database 'BObd'

Comment: yes, they'll, more info you can read from this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6488591/952129

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25769/discussion-between-chinchu-and-said-kaldybaev)

Comment: but how it is possible in ruby on rails.i did not get.Please give me a clear picture

Comment: it's not ruby on rails issue actually, in ODBC should be command console, you should enter and grant previlligies there